Understanding exception with loaded DLLs
I have a pipeline system that uses the TPL Dataflow in C#. My application works as follow:

Load Step Configuration from database
For each step of the pipeline load the dll corresponding to the specific step
Call (inside the pipeline) the Execute() method of the block aka step

A step can throw an exception so what I did was wrap the call to the execute method of the loaded step into a try-catch. The exception will be caught, but I have no information i.e. stack trace of where it happened. For example I get this:

24/04/08 13:31:48.914 [Error      ] Step CalculateDestinationToWarehouse: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
at LoadSingleArticleIntoWarehouse.CalculateDestinationToWarehouse.Execute(ILogicPointContextData data)
at Plms.Pipelines.Infrastructure.Builders.PipelineBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass3_1.<b__0>d.MoveNext() in E:\folder\folder\PipelineBuilder.cs:line 41

Which is okay, but this points to the main application and doesn't give me anything on the step side. Therefore finding the actual line where the exception occurred is difficult.
What is even stranger is that the path specified by the catch at the end points to a folder on my PC whereas the application is installed on a totally different machine.
What should I do here? Should I try to add the .pdb file for every step? In this case is the pdb file loaded automatically by the runtime? Is it clear what I am trying to do?

EDIT
How do you load the corresponding dll?
I load the dll by doing this:
var dllFiles = Directory.GetFiles(_path, "*.dll");

foreach (var dllFile in dllFiles)
{

    var dllKey = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(dllFile)?.Split('.')?.LastOrDefault();

    // Match Dll with database Dll name configuration
    if (attributeDefs.Any(x => x.Key.ToLower() == dllKey?.ToLower()))
    {
        AddDllStep(dllFile, dllKey);
    }
}

 private void AddDllStep(string assemblyPath, string key)
 {
     if (!File.Exists(assemblyPath))
     {
         _logger.LogError($"No DLL found for path: [{assemblyPath}]");
         return;
     }

     var assemblyDll = Assembly.LoadFrom(assemblyPath);

     var stepType = assemblyDll.GetTypes()
                               .FirstOrDefault(t => typeof(IStep).IsAssignableFrom(t) && !t.IsInterface && !t.IsAbstract);

     if (stepType == null)
     {
         _logger.LogError($"There is no DLL implementing IStep interface");
         return;
     }
     AddOrUpdateStep(key, stepType);
 }

The AddOrUpdateStep() will add the Type to a ConcurrentDictionary<string, Type>();
What does your CalculateDestinationToWarehouse.Execute method look like?
This is the point where the Execute method of the Step gets called (this is done for every step instance):
try
{
    return await step.Execute(input);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    context.Logger?.LogError($"Step {step.StepKey}: {ex}");
    return input;
}

Since each step could throw a different exception i decided to use the general Exception type. Could that be the issue?
Does loading dll in "chain mode" affect the stack trace? Meaning that if i have Software A that loads Dll B and uses it and then Dll B that loads Dll C will Dll C lose the stack trace when an exception is occured?

Are you sure you are not doing anything to drop the stacktrace, like catch(exception e){... throw e}? What does your CalculateDestinationToWarehouse.Execute method look like? Stack traces are captured even without debug information, but may, due to optimizations, not match the source exactly. The path your are seeing is likely the source path on the build machine, and that should not really be relevant.

How do you "load the dll corresponding to the specific step"? Do you use Assembly.Load (and friends). One generally doesn't load DLLs in .NET code, one loads assemblies (which an contain multiple modules, etc)

@Flydog57  i have added more information about my project to answer your questions!
